# Add a contact from an email address within email text

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, microsoft-outlook-2011, microsoft-office-2011

I came to Office/Outlook 2011 from Mac Mail, and now I find that I'm unable to do something that I need to do ALL THE TIME.

In Mail, if there was an email address within the text of an email message that I received, I could highlight and right-click the email address text and then either

-- Add a New Contact
-- Add to Existing Contact

Is there a simple, elegant way to add this functionality to Outlook?

AppleScript? Automator?

Tearing my hair out here -- in my line of work, I end up having to do this type of thing all day long, and constantly copying, leaving the email, creating a new contact, pasting, etc. is making me crazy. Sometimes I have an email with 30-50 addresses in it, ALL of which need to be added as contacts.

Has anybody got (or can anyone easily create) an AppleScript or Automator action that does this?